# Format date in table with postgres PERN stack

Tags: reactjs, postgresql

I have a Postgres table with dates and I am having trouble to format the date the way I want it. I want it to store the date as yyyy/mm/dd. However, it stores and displays yyyy-mmTdd-hh-mm-ssL (see image).

In my app I have a context API and I iterate over the table to display the values. I have looked at the documentation and tried to set the date values correctly but it continues to display time and timezone. So frustrating as it displays correctly in pgAdmin but not in the app.

picture of table display with unwanted timezone data

[image: picture of table display with unwanted timezone data]

picture of postgres table in pgAdmin with correct date display

[image: picture of postgres table in pgAdmin with correct date display]

It displays this in the table: 2020-10-20T07:00:00.000Z
And it should display: 2020-10-20

From Postman get request I get this:

```
"data": {
    "watertrack": {
        "id": "110",
        "fcbc_rec_date": "2017-10-26T07:00:00.000Z",
        "hold_total": null 
}
```

Comment: Could you please copy the content of this output in this post?

Comment: @FrankHeikens It displays this in the table: 2020-10-20T07:00:00.000Z And it should display: 2020-10-20

Comment: A `date` column does not have any format and it does not store a time value either. The format you see is applied by the application you are using to display the value.

Comment: Are you sure this is the same data from the same table? The dates are already different and pgAdmin thinks it’s a date and a date doesn’t have a time zone

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I added the Postman res data. I enter the date as yyyy-mm-dd and somewhere it gets the timestamp. So is it Postgres?

Comment: No, Postgres will not add a time to a date on its own.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that is what I thought. So in the PERN stack when I use app.post and insert the value into the table it is being altered in the chain.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name. Actually it will, `select '01/01/2021'::date::timestamp; 01/01/2021 00:00:00`, which I suspect is happening here. Something is casting a date to a timestamp.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver: well, Postgres doesn't pull that cast out of thin air (on its own). If that is happening, something else (not Postgres) did that.

Comment: When I created the table I did select DATE, I did not select the timestamp option. In PGAdmin it displays as yyyy-mm-dd, when the data is queried by my app it returns with a timestamp and locale.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up with is to truncate the date as the data is mapped to the table. I realize this is a front end solution. Still did not figure out where the date is being mutated. Nonetheless, I added the function to the  elements with dates and it works perfectly.

```
const handleDateTruncation = (str) => {
        if(str !== null) {
            return str.substr(0, 10);
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }
```

In the jsx...

```
{tracker && tracker.map((el) => {
      return (
          <tr key={el.id}>
              <td>{handleDateTruncation(el.start_date)}</td>
          </tr>
      )
}
```

This returns the date as yyyy-mm-dd without the timestamp and locale.